# Spring Data Couchbase Unable to load view

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, couchbase, couchbase-view

We are using Spring Data Couchbase project and when trying to execute a existing view in production running into the below error

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: 
Could not load view "fooCount" for design doc "_design/foo"; 
nested exception is com.couchbase.client.protocol.views.InvalidViewException: 
Could not load view "fooCount" for design doc "_design/foo"
```

Below is our Spring Data Repository Definition

```
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo,String>{

       @View(designDocument="_design/foo",viewName="fooCount")
       public Long fooCount();

}
```

Can anyone provide an example of executing query using couchbase views? 
The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#couchbase.repository.views) seems to be missing an example of doing it.

Comment: can you confirm which version of Spring Data Couchbase you are using? Also, the designDocument parameter of the annotation should omit the `_design/` prefix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer:

1) Repository finder method name should start with "find" for ex. findFooByName. 
2) A view name by "fooByName" must exist in production mode in Couchbase for it to execute successfully.

```
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo,String>{
       public List<Foo> findFooByName(Query query);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm still confused by your answer. Do you use or not the @View annotation on your method ? If you do then does the name of the method matter ?

Comment: Please consider adding more details to your answer